# search for text pattern in a directory using perl script

Tags: perl, grep

could anyone please share with me a snippet where i can do a grep search in perl file. Example,
 i need this grep: `grep 1115852311 /opt/files/treated/postpaid/*`

to be done in perl script and print all the matches

tried the below, but did not work :

```
my $start_dir= "\opt\files\treated\postpaid\";
my $file_name = "*";
my @filematches;
opendir(DIR, "$start_dir");
@xml_files = grep(1115852311,readdir(DIR));
print @xml_files;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good start would be to read [the documentation for `grep()`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/grep). If you do, you'll see that Perl's `grep()` works rather differently to the Unix `grep` command. The Unix command just looks for text in a list of files. The Perl version works on any list of data and returns any elements in that list for which an arbitrary Boolean expression is true.

A Perl version of the Unix command would look something like this:

```
while (<$some_open_filehandle>) {
  print if /$some_string/;
}
```

That's not quite what you want, but we can use it as a start. First, let's write something that takes a filename and string and checks whether the string appears in the file:

```
sub is_string_in_file {
  my ($filename, $string) = @_;

  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open file '$filename': $!\n";

  return grep { /$string/ } <$fh>;
}
```

We can now use that in a loop which uses `readdir()` to get a list of files.

```
my @files;

my $dir = '/opt/files/treated/postpaid/';
opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
  if (is_string_in_file("$dir$file", 1115852311) {
     push @files, "$dir$file";
  }
}
```

After running that code, the list of files that contain your string will be in `@files`.

You might want to look at `glob()` instead of `opendir()` and `readdir()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your input , it helped. i use the below snippet and it worked

Answer (score 1):

used the below snippet to achieve what i wanted

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub is_string_in_file {
  my ($filename, $string) = @_;
  open my $fh, '<', $filename 
    or die "Cannot open file \n";


while(my $line = <$fh>){
  if($line =~ /$string/){
    print $string;
    print $filename."\n";
  } 
}
  #return grep { $_ eq $string } <$fh>;
}

my @files;

my $dir = '/opt/files/treated/postpaid/';
opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    is_string_in_file("$dir$file", 1115852311);
}
```

Comment: I've changed my `is_string_in_file()` subroutine to use a regex check rather than the (rather naive) string comparison that I used before. I think you'll find that the `is_string_in_file()` subroutine will be far more flexible if you leave it returning a Boolean flag (as my version does) and handle any printing yo want outside of it.